# Jsp unscrollable and fix menu

Tags: html, jsp, menu, jsp-tags

In my JSP page There is a menu with 14 options in the left side and menu description at the right side. I have created hyperlink in the same page on the menu click. Menu description has lengthy stuff. And the size of the page is much more than the menu. My problem is when I click on any menu item at left excluding first menu item the page scrolls down and menu disappears. Is there can be any way to make the left side (menu) unscrollable, and fixed in the position. Only The right side of the page will scroll. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. make left div `position:fixed`
2. make height of right div fix and give `overflow:auto`